# Can I receive stronger signals from nearby routers if I get a powerful antenna?

Tags: signal, antenna

I have a netgear wireless wireless adapter without a antenna which i can receive signals from routers which never appear on my macbook or phone but there is AP rate limiting.

Like if my friend lives in an apartment and I want to play a prank on him and crack his WPS pin I can see his wifi in my netgear wireless adapter but when I attempt to attack him. It says "AP rate limiting detected!"

I get around -40 to -30dBM signal strength from his wifi which is not sufficient.

My question is if I get a stronger wireless adapter with a 5dBi antenna, can I receive stronger signals from his router like at least -20dBM?

Comment: 60 dBm??? That's one fricking kilowatt! even 30–40 dBm are 1 to 10W , which is 2 to 20 times as much as any AP might legally transmit. I don't know what you're looking at, but you don't seem to have the slightest. I'm really not convinced this is an engineering question at all.

Comment: Typical RSSI is -40 dBm high to -80dBm low

Comment: If he is a 'friend' - far easier to pop around there and sneak a picture of the label on the bottom of his router.

Comment: @Marcus Müller Sorry I forgot to add the minus symbol before the signal strength. I know it makes a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

Antennas themselves do not add power.

Using a different (directional) antenna allows you to "focus" the signals, so instead of sending the signals in all directions you send/receive them to one location. That's how long distance WiFi is done.

As mentioned in the comments, 60 dBm is 1 kW and not achievable as WiFi is limited to 0.1 W (20 dBm) to 1 W (30 dBm) depending on your country.

*I get around 30-40dBM signal strength from his wifi which is not sufficient.*

Not possible as 30 dBm is the maximum. I think you mean -40 to -30 dBm.

By itself that is enough signal as long as the signal/noise ratio is sufficient. In your case the noise and other disturbing signals might be the actual problem as other WiFi access points in the neighborhood are probably transmitting on the same frequencies.

Comment: Yep. -40 dBm is something I'd still consider "excellent reception" for WiFi.